# glossaries-extra does not recognise glossaries commands

Tags: glossaries, capacity

I have a question regarding the glossaries package. In my thesis I use this package to create a list of symbols/nomenclature. Without the `glossaries` package and only using `glossaries-extra` everything is fine, however when adding the former TeX returns `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \RequirePackage`. In the documentation it is stated that `glossaries-extra` requires `glossaries` but for some reason it thows an error for me. Removing `\usepackage{glossaries}` resolves the error. However in this case, command provided by the package such as `\glossarysection` are not recognised and thus throws `Undefined control sequence. \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2]` when attempting the following (which should work according to the `glossaries-extra` manual (page 192)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[symbols,stylemods={tree},record]{glossaries-extra}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{latin}{Latin letters}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
src={numbers.bib},
type=symbols,
group={letters},% assign group label
set-widest,% needed for 'alttree' styles
save-locations=false
]
\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=alttreegroup,\printunsrtglossaryunitsetup{section}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{\subsection*{Summary}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: it compiles if you remove \usepackage{glossaries}, glossaries-extras will then load it internally itself. But I wonder why it loops.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, I was aware of that. Though maybe the question was not clear enough. I will edit it.

Comment: it looks like a clear bug. \ProcessOptionsX doesn't like the \expandafter content of the   \DeclareOptionX* declaration. Report it to the author.

Comment: Many thanks Ulrike, I will do that!